# Get-ADGroupMember : The operation being requested was not performed because the user has not been authenticated

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am running a script to get members of a specific group. This almost all groups, except a select few, where it results in

`Get-ADGroupMember : The operation being requested was not performed because the user has not been authenticated`

The code:

```
Get-ADGroupMember "Server Admins" -Server "abc.xyz.com" -Recursive
```

I can view the members by doing

```
Get-ADGroup "Server Admins" -Server "abc.xyz.com" -Properties members | select -ExpandProperty members
```

But I want to access the member's properties like samaccountname, not just view their display name. Why am I getting the `ADGroupMember` error on some groups?

Comment: Are there different permissions on those groups that would prevent your account from reading them?

Comment: Do the groups contain other groups that are not in the same domain? You are using the Recursive switch but getting the members property isn't recursive.

Comment: I can use the `get-adgroup ... | select -expandprop members` method to view all the users/groups in the groups that fail `get-adgroupmember`. I use Recursive in case there is a group member of another group, so I can get all the users in the subset group